# Qt FramelessWindowHint and WA_TranslucentBackground Font Rendering

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7

I am writing an application with a custom window shell. The shell has rounded corners and transparency. Here is the sample code of how I am doing this:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow (void) : QMainWindow (NULL, Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
{
    setAttribute (Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    setAttribute (Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground   );
}
```

The problem is whenever I use WA_TranslucentBackground with FramelessWindowHint, the font rendering becomes awful, see image below. I have a custom application style set through a global css. I tried using other fonts such as Segoe UI however that font also becomes changed.

[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening and what I can do to fix this problem. I am using C++ with Qt 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I may have found a solution. First of all, you can use QWidget::setMask in order to get rounded corners if you prefer to not use Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground. Here is the sample code I came up with:

```
void MyWindow::setVisible (bool visible)
{
    // Call the default event
    QMainWindow::setVisible (visible);

    // Set a rounded mask (size() needs to be correct)
    QBitmap t (size());
    t.fill (Qt::color0);

    QPainter p (&t);
    p.setBrush (Qt::color1);
    p.drawRoundedRect (rect(), 5, 5);

    setMask (t);
}
```

For transparency you have to make the font prefer antialiasing. You can put this at the start of the application.

```
    QFont font = QApplication::font();
    font.setStyleStrategy (QFont::PreferAntialias);
    QApplication::setFont (font);
```

Not perfect but it fixed the problem I was having.